# target element not showing active class in tab-pane

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabpanel

I have implemented tab using bootstrap, there are 3 tabs and each of them has contents in them, but while I am executing the code all the contents of active tab is not visible, content is visible only after any other tab is clicked, when checked on inspect element does not show active class.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="all-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#all" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">All</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Cash</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Miles</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content pt-3" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="all-tab">
  Content.........                                    
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
  Content.........                                    
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
  Content.........
  </div>
</div>
```

in inspect div element only shows three classes (class="tab-pane fade show") but not active class.
[image: inspect element panel]

Answer (score 0):

@conrad

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

add this script link to your shipify theme.liquid head section

```
 <a class="nav-link active" id="all-tab" data-toggle="tab"
```

the data toggle need a unique id  you do not mention  it

you put the same data-toggle  change relevant tab id

Comment: according to w3 example (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab&stacked=h) data-toggle is same for every nav-link

Comment: problem is that i have assigned four classes to class attr (class="tab-pane fade show active") but if you see image(above) in inspect element panel where it is highlighted, active class is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add active class to `li` tag and add `in` class inside first div which you need to display

***Demo Code*** :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <!--add active to li-->
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" id="all-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#all" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">All</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Cash</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Miles</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content pt-3" id="myTabContent">
  <!--added class in-->
  <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="all-tab">
    Content1.........
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    Content2.........
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
    Content3.........
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: problem is that i have assigned four classes to class attr (class="tab-pane fade show active") but if you see image(above) in inspect element panel where it is highlighted, active class is not present. if i write custom class like "myclass" it shows but for some reason active class is not showing

Comment: did you tried above code ? does that shows that behaviour ?

Comment: tried above code but didnt solve the active class problem which i require to show one tab open when page is loaded (i have main tab-pane and above code tab-content is inside main tab-pane, so when i switch to no. 2 main tab-pane then i get the above mentioned problem)

Comment: it does load first div .  click on run snippet and see result yourself .